# Xamarin.Forms ImageButton doesn't work, clicking does not work and debug breakpoint doesn't get hit at all on iOS only

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have an ImageButton that works fine in Android but not in iOS, the same exact code ( both XAML, code-behind and ViewModel ) work fine on another view in iOS but not for this one.

No breakpoint gets hit for the second one, neither the code behind event or the ViewModel Command, and the background is pretty wide on that button I've changed the color to see and it's the exact same as the first one which works.

I'm confused as to why it's not working.

**Code that works:**

Xaml:

```
<ImageButton Grid.Row="1"
             Grid.RowSpan="4"
             x:Name="SaveIconName"
             BorderColor="Transparent"
             BackgroundColor="Transparent"
             HeightRequest="24"
             WidthRequest="24"
             Aspect="AspectFill"
             HorizontalOptions="End"
             VerticalOptions="Center"
             Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type vm:PartnerViewModel}}, Path=SavePlaceTapped}"
                             CommandParameter="{Binding Place.PlaceId}"
                             Clicked="Save_Clicked"/>
```

Code-behind:

```
namespace App.Views
{
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class WorkingPage : ContentPage
{
    WorkingViewModel workingViewModel;
    public ISavedPlaceRepository savedPlaceRepository =>
        DependencyService.Get<ISavedPlaceRepository>();

    public string SaveIcon { get; set; }

    public WorkingPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = workingViewModel = new WorkingViewModel();
    }
    public WorkingPage(WorkingModel popupModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = workingViewModel = new WorkingViewModel(popupModel);
        SaveIconName.Source = "icon_heart_red_96.png";
    }

    private void Save_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
        {
            Vibration.Vibrate(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10));
        }
        SaveIconName.Source = "icon_heart_full_red_96.png";
    }
}
```

}

**Code that doesn't work:**

Xaml:

```
<ImageButton Grid.RowSpan="3"
             x:Name="SaveIconName"
             BorderColor="Transparent"
             BackgroundColor="Transparent"
             HeightRequest="24"
             WidthRequest="24"
             Aspect="AspectFill"
             HorizontalOptions="End"
             VerticalOptions="Center"
             Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type vm:NotPartnerPopupViewModel}}, Path=SavePlaceTapped}"
                                         CommandParameter="{Binding Place.PlaceId}"
                                     Clicked="Save_Clicked"/>
```

Code-behind:

```
namespace App.Views
{
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class NotPartnerPopupPage : Popup
{
    NotWorkingViewModel notWorkingViewModel;
    public ISavedPlaceRepository savedPlaceRepository =>
        DependencyService.Get<ISavedPlaceRepository>();

    public NotWorkingPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = notWorkingViewModel = new NotWorkingViewModel();
    }

    public NotWorkingPage(NotWorkingModel popupModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DisplayInfo mainDisplayInfo = new DisplayInfo();
        if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
        {
            MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                mainDisplayInfo = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo;
                Size size = new Size();
                var pixelWidth = ConvertToPixels(mainDisplayInfo.Width, mainDisplayInfo.Density);
                size.Width = pixelWidth - 40;
                size.Height = 300;
                this.Size = size;
                InsideFrame.Padding = new Thickness(10);
                InsideFrame.Margin = new Thickness(-54);
            });

        }
        else
        {
            mainDisplayInfo = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo;
            Size size = new Size();
            var pixelWidth = ConvertToPixels(mainDisplayInfo.Width, mainDisplayInfo.Density);
            size.Width = pixelWidth;
            size.Height = 300;
            this.Size = size;
            InsideFrame.Padding = new Thickness(0);
            InsideFrame.Margin = new Thickness(-10);
        }
        BindingContext = notWorkingViewModel = new NotWorkingViewModel(popupModel);

        SaveIconName.Source = "icon_heart_red_96.png";
    }

    public void Save_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Vibration.Vibrate(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10));
        SaveIconName.Source = "icon_heart_full_red_96.png";
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Maybe you could open up what Xamarin builds for iOS in XCode and see if there are any obvious problems?

Comment: Thank you, how could I do that ?

Comment: What's the `ISavedPlaceRepository`,`NotWorkingViewModel `  and `NotWorkingViewModel`? If it is convinient for you, could you please post a basic demo to github or onedriver so that we can test on our side?

Comment: I would like to, unfortunately I can't share any code as it is private to the company but I can tell you that the `ISavedPlaceRepository` is the same used for the working code and both viewmodels are almost the same as the working code, but the thing is that since the button doesn't get hit at all it feels like no matter what it would be it wouldn't even throw an error, but I don't know if it is related but the working button is on an actual page as opposed to the not working button which is on a popup, but the thing is that every other button on the popup works, it's only this one

Comment: If you add an old school `Debug.WriteLine("HERE")` kind of statement does it print or is the clicked handler not even being invoked?

Comment: @CodingLumis the clicked handler isn't being invoked which is the thing that confuses me, do you think it could be formatting ( margin, padding ) ?

Comment: Maybe this could be of help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/troubleshooting/questions/debugging-with-xcode

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I don't know what the problem is but I've changed the margin of the frame to a less expanded frame and it worked, must've been the artificial frame stretch that was messing up the controls